# дублируется addEventListener одной и той же функции

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

```js
const b = document.getElementById('btn');

const f = () => {
  console.log('asdf');
}

const c = () => {
  // const f = () => {
  //   console.log('asdf');
  // }
  b.addEventListener('click', f);
}

c();
c();
```

```html
<button id="btn">action</button>
```

в первом сниппете к кнопке дважды привязывается функция f из глобальной области видимости. в результате при клике на кнопку она выполнится один раз.

```js
const b = document.getElementById('btn');

//const f = () => {
//  console.log('asdf');
//}

const c = () => {
  const f = () => {
     console.log('asdf');
  }
  b.addEventListener('click', f);
}

c();
c();
```

```html
<button id="btn">action</button>
```

во втором сниппете также дважды привязываем функцию f к кнопке, только теперь из локальной области видимости, в результате при клике функция выполняется дважды. почему в первом случае addEventListener перезаписывается, а во втором нет?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Полагаю, потому что в первом случае - это одна и та же функция, а во втором - две разных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первом случае назначается обработчиком одна и та же функция. Второй раз одна и та же функция не добавляется.

> Если зарегистрировано несколько одинаковых EventListener на одном EventTarget с одинаковыми параметрами, дублирующиеся слушатели игнорируются.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Во втором случае Вы при каждом вызове создаёте новую функцию. Как результат добавляется новый обработчик события.

Comment: не могу понять, почему во втором случае так происходит, даже если вместо анонимной const f = () использовать именованную function f()

Comment: Смысл от этого не меняется. Каждый новый вызов такой функции - это создание нового экземпляра в другой области памяти.